# How to add child columns / divide columns in datatables.js

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a dataset with child columns. How can I emulate using datatables.js? 
**Ex:**

```
+-------+----------------------------+-----------+
| Name  | Marks                      | Rank      |
|       +---------+----------+-------+           |
|       |Internal | External | Total |           |
+-------+---------+----------+-------+-----------+
| Sandy |  24     |  55      | 79    |Distinction| 
+-------+---------+----------+-------+-----------+
| Bill  |  13     |  25      | 38    | Fail      |
+-------+---------+----------+-------+-----------+
```

Currently I am using [this](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html), but when I save the table as csv / xls, I get

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| Name  |Internal | External | Total | Rank      |
|------------------------------------------------|
| Sandy |  24     |  55      | 79    |Distinction| 
|------------------------------------------------|
| Bill  |  13     |  25      | 38    | Fail      |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

But we have an option of adding [child rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html).

**Is there any way to have child columns? Or can we divide a column?**

Comment: The above is totally doable in excel. And we come across data structures like these when we are handling student data. Quote: `Downvoting a question without a reason, shows the mindset of the developer!!`

Comment: We are turning into a world of Ferengi, probably due in large part to the recent access to anonymous public criticism.  'Tis sad.  Perhaps we will decide as a world that we are not going to be the world's terminal disease, but just its only disease.  But I wax philosophical.  I actually have an answer below, FWIW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with the current version of DataTables. See
[this question](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/72613/#Comment_72613) on the DataTables forums.

> There is no option for that at the moment. Sorry.
>
> Allan

From the creator of the plugin.

You noted in a comment that it is possible in excel to make these tables, but with the current version of DataTables there is no way to automatically export your DataTable in this format.

**Edit:**
[Here's](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/92956/#Comment_92956) a much more recent forum post confirming that this feature is not available.

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate the structure, but not the layout.  A JSON logical equivalent of your data would be:

```
[{
    "Name": "Sandy",
    "Marks": {
        "Internal": "24",
        "External": "55",
        "Total": "79"
    },
    "Rank": "Distinction"
}, {
    "Name": "Bill",
    "Marks": {
        "Internal": "13",
        "External": "25",
        "Total": "38"
    },
    "Rank": "Fail"
}]
```

The way you might set this up using the child table trick in the link is to put Name, Rank and Marks in the table, and when you click on a line to open it, you'll see Internal, External and Total as "child rows" in the embedded table.

I suspect that what you are doing to get the layout you have is putting two rows in your header.  I don't know Excel well enough to know whether or not this JSON structure will import in such a way as to automatically give you the layout you want.  If it does, perhaps you can consider some sort of hack where you prepare one structure for the table and another for the Excel.

Comment: I can use child rows, but I cannot query them using search. Do you know by any means how to query data present in child rows? You can [test here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html). Thnx for the workaround, But I feel @Chris's answer is right.

Comment: No, you can't.  The reason that you can't becomes clear when you look at the underlying HTML (which you can do by going into debug on some line of code in some event handler, and then examining the elements).  You'll see that each of the child rows is in a table inside its respective row in the datatable.  Armed with that information (and a good deal of will and spare time) you could probably devise a search capability that hooks into the existing one, although it would be tough to find search criteria that were in the child set and not in its parent row. ...

Comment: ... Perhaps you could put the child columns redundantly in invisible columns in the parent table to work around that.  However, it's probably easier to say you can't do it.  Can't is a relative term, which each of us has to decide for himself.  I probably wouldn't go to this trouble, personally; I suspect I'd look for an easier way to do what I wanted.